# Free White Label Travel Tour/Activities website software?

Tags: search-engine, travel

I've used white label flight software to host my own domain with deals linked through the WL software.

However, my provider (travelpayouts) doesn't do more than flights/hotels, and I'm looking for a similar whitelabel option that does things like boat tours, museum deals, bungy jumping, skydiving etc - activities/tours on sale.  I've found viator, but as far as I can tell you can't have it on your domain, you have to just link to theirs.

I don't just want a referral URL, I want to use it as a whitelabel as in people would type in marksdomain.com and see it, rather than being directed to a subdomain like viator has.